#  access associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, associative-array

I am using Code Igniter and I get following data structure after executing a query at DB

```
array
'application' => 
    array
    0 => 
        object(stdClass)[19]
        public 'app_id' => string '16' (length=2)
        public 'app_name' => string 'dddddddd' (length=8)
        public 'app_title' => string 'sdfsdf' (length=6)
        public 'app_comments' => string 'sdfsdf' (length=6)
        public 'active_flg' => string 'N' (length=1)
```

I know one way to access the values is

```
foreach($application as $key => $value)
    $value->app_id
```

But I know that I will get only one record each time so I want to access the elements without using foreach.
I have tried to **$application->app_id and $application['app_id']** but I keep getting error.

Can anybody please help me to understand how to access the data directly??

Comment: You should access like `$application[0]['app_id']`

Comment: Actually, it should be `$application[0]->app_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using multidimensional mixed type of array, with numeric indexing on the second level. SO, while accessing the values, you have to use them too. Like

```
echo $array['application'][0]->app_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to show you the structure of your array and how you might access it...

```
$objArray = array('app_id' => 7, 'app_name' => 'apps demo', 'app_title' => 'apps demo title');

$applicationArray = array('application' => array((object)$objArray));

// access the array
print $applicationArray['application'][0]->app_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting that result by doing the following?

```
$res = $this->db->query('select * from application limit 1')->result();
```

If so, you can put that result into an object by doing:

```
$app = $this->db->query('select * from application limit 1')->row();
```

This way you can access the properties as follows:

```
echo $app->app_id;
```

You should check out [codeigniters manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) on getting results.